# Perform multiple aggregations on a single column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I would like to return a count on the number of records for multiple conditions.

A single query will return what I need:

```
SELECT count(id) AS "support" FROM mail WHERE mail_class = "support"
```

However I need to return multiple counts. I could easily achieve this in php by making separate calls to the database, but that seems un-necessary and would most likely cause a delay.

I have tried using a union but that did not work.

Comment: can you give an example of the result you are expecting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregation.  It looks something like this:

```
SELECT sum(mail_class = 'support') as support,
       sum(mail_class = 'who know what you really want') as othercount
FROM mail;
```

Comment: That worked exactly, sorry if I was a little vague in my question, I wasn't quite sure how to phrase it. You must have understood to some degree though! Thanks @Gordon

Comment: Thanks for the term 'conditional aggregation'. I have been using this SUM(condition) example in a few of my own answers lately and didn't know what to call it.